# IF statement not validating in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this php script on one page which takes variables from input fields:

```
if($fname <> "" and $lname <> "" and $ydept <> "") {
    if ($percentage >= "85") {
        mail ($myEmail, $mailSubject, $msgBody, $header);
        mail ($userEmail, $sentMailSubject, $sentMailBody, $sentHeader);
        $filename = "blah.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666, set folder to 777
        $text = "\n" . str_pad($fname, 25) . "" . str_pad($lname, 25) . "" . str_pad($empID, 15) . "" . str_pad($doh, 15) . "";

        $fp = fopen ($filename, "a"); # a = append to the file. w = write to the file (create new if doesn't exist)
        if ($fp) {
            fwrite ($fp, $text);
            fclose ($fp);
            #echo ("File written");
        }
        else {
            #echo ("File was not written");
        }
        header ("Location: yes.php?fname=$fname&type=$type");
    }
    else {
        header ("Location: didnotpass.php?percent=$percentage&type=$type");
    }
}
else {
    header ("Location: empty.php?type=$type");
}
```

And the didnotpass.php script is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['percentage'])) {
    $percent = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['percent'])));
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['type'])));

    if ($type == "Clinical") {
?>
The Certificate of Attendance has been completed yet, but your score of $percent% is less then the passing score of 85%.<br><br>
Please <b><a href="C.php">Click Here</a></b> to retake the certification.
<?php
    }
    else {
?>
The Certificate of Attendance has been completed yet, but your score of $percent% is less then the passing score of 85%.<br><br>
Please <b><a href="nonC.php">Click Here</a></b> to retake the certification.
<?php
    }
}
else {
?>
Please <b><a href="start.php">Go To Certification Homepage</a></b> to start the certification.
<?php
}
?>
```

The issue I am having is whether or not the score is 85% or not, it goes to the last else statement:

```
Please <b><a href="start.php">Go To Certification Homepage</a></b> to start the certification.
```

Is my IF statement correct:

```
if ($percentage >= "85")
```

I am thinking it is working correctly because it is routing to the correct page but the IF/ELSE statement in the didnotpass.php is not working correctly. Anyone can help me fix it?

Comment: That seems easy enough to check: What does `var_dump($percentage);` before the `if` condition give you and why are you quoting the number?

Comment: My URL for nopass.php looks like this: http://www.imed.com/sc/nopass.php?percent=38&type=Clinical

Comment: You know, not that this solves your problem, but it's probably a bad idea to use quotes around numbers. Just do `85` without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the query string parameters for `percent` aren't consistent:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['percentage'])) {
    $percent = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['percent'])));
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['type'])));
```

it should be

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['percent'])) {
    $percent = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['percent'])));
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['type'])));
```

The if statement refers to `$_GET['percentage']` instead of `$_GET['percent']`

Comment: percentage, i knew i was missing it somewhere! Thanks JLC. Problem fixed!

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($percentage >= "85")
```

should be:

```
if ($percentage >= 85)
```

can't have quotes around a number and then expect it to evaluate to >=. It will treat it as a string. You may need to parse it as an integer as well depending on what type it is.

Comment: Thank you. Your recommendation just fixed the comparing string to integer but JLC's fixed the IF statement issue